# Ugin's Conjurant vs. un-preventable damage

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I had [Ugin's Conjurant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUgin%27s%5d%2b%5bConjurant%5d) with 10 +1/+1 counters on it (and no other effects modifying its toughness,) and my opponent cast a [Banefire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBanefire%5d) for 5 damage on it, would +1/+1 counters get removed from the Conjurant, as well as the damage being dealt, killing the Conjurant?

Relevant text on Banefire:

> Banefire deals X damage to any target.
>   If X is 5 or more, this spell can't be countered and the damage can't be prevented.

and on Ugin's Conjurant:

> If damage would be dealt to Ugin's Conjurant while it has a +1/+1 counter on it, prevent that damage and remove that many +1/+1 counters from Ugin's Conjurant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If Ugin's Conjurant takes damage that cannot be prevented, it will both take the damage and lose that many +1/+1 counters. This is covered by [rule 615.12](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Prevention_effect):

> Some effects state that damage “can’t be prevented.” If unpreventable damage would be dealt, any applicable prevention effects are still applied to it. **Those effects won’t prevent any damage, but any additional effects they have will take place.** Existing damage prevention shields won’t be reduced by damage that can’t be prevented.

So, if the Ugin's Conjurant has 10 +1/+1 counters on it and it is hit with a Banefire for 5 damage, it will end up as a 5/5 with 5 damage marked and it will die.